# Como fazer um array de arrays para um Insert multiplo no mysql com Node?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Preciso fazer um insert de múltiplos valores no banco, para isso preciso de um `array` de `array`.

O primeiro valor de cada `array` será fixo e o segundo elemento irei alterar com um for provavelmente:

```
var values = 
[
    ['281', 'Highway 71'],
    ['281', 'Lowstreet 4'],
    ['281', 'Apple st 652'],
    ['281', 'Mountain 21'],
    ['281', 'Valley 345'],
    ['281', 'Ocean blvd 2'],
    ['281', 'Green Grass 1']
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Descobri como fazer:

```
for (let index = 0; index < list.length; index++) 
{
    sqlObj[index] = [lastId, list[index]];
}
```

Comment: E por que isso resolve o problema? Poderia explicar o que fez no código?

Comment: Claro @Woss ...Para inserir múltiplos dados no banco com node é necessário um array de arrays ( Como pode ser visto em "Insert Multiple Records" aqui: [link](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql_insert.asp) )

Comment: Com o for que postei, em cada posição de um Array (sqlObj) ele adiciona um array contendo o ultimo id (fixo) de um insert que fiz + o elemento da lista que eu preciso...